# Application of Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

Let A be finite set, $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^{n}:A\to \mathbb{R}$ non-negative and with the following property for every $\sum \lambda_{i}=1$: for any $g=\sum \lambda_{i}f_i$ there exists $a\in A$ s.t. $g(a)<1$. Prove that there exists probability measure P s.t. $\int f_idP<1$.

only hints please

**Attempts**

1)My first guess is to consider $M:=\sup \limits_{a\in A,i\in [1,n]}f_i(a)$ and functional $r_{a_{0}}:C(A)\to \mathbb{R}$ to be $r(f)=\frac{f(a_{0})}{M}$. This is a positive, linear and bounded functional, thus by RMK theorem we can write it as $r(f)=\int f dP$. Thus, $\int f_idP=r(f_i)<1$.

Because I didn't use the hypothesis, I probably made a mistake.

2)Alternate approach is to look at convex sets $A=\{g>1\}$ and $B=\{\sum \lambda_{i}f_i\}$. These are convex, disjoint and A is open. Thus, there exists linear functional s.t. $inf_{A}\phi\geq sup_{B}\phi$. From here I was trying to prove (or disprove) that $\phi$ is positive (or bounded) and that $\phi(f_i)<1$ for all $f_i$.

But the lack of structure makes it hard to prove these two properties.

3)Consider linear subspace $C:=\{\sum c_i f_i: c_i\in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $D:=\{\sum \lambda_{i}f_i:\sum \lambda_i\leq 1\}$. Then D is radial/absorbing. Now all I need is a functional on D and then we can extend it on $C(A)$.

Comment: Your second approach seems most promising. Personally, I would replace $A$ by $\{g \mid g(a) \geq 1 \forall a \in A\}$. By assumption, you know that the closed convex set $A$ is disjoint from the compact convex set $B := \{\sum \lambda_i f_i \}$. Now you know (renormalize if necessary) that there is a nontrivial functional $\phi : \Bbb{R}^A \to \Bbb{R}$ with $\phi(x) > \phi(y)$ for all $x \in A$, $y \in B$. Renormalize again so that $\phi(1,\dots,1) = 1$. I will leave the rest to you.

Comment: if $\phi(1,..,1)<0$ then normalizing will change the order of the inequality.

Comment: right, so if I can show $\phi(g)\geq 1$ for some $g\geq 1$, then by scaling we have positivity and by the inequality we get $\phi(f_i)<1$.

Comment: First renormalize so that $\phi(x) > \phi(y)$ for $x \in A, y\in B$. Then verify that we have $\phi(e_i) \geq 0$ for all $i$, where $e_i$ is the ith unit vector. Since $\phi$ is nontrivial, we must have $\phi(e_i) > 0$ for at least one $i$. I leave the rest to you.

Comment: $\phi(0...,0,1,0,...,0)=0$ for all i. The map is a linear functional and not a |A|-linear map; because we get problems like $c\phi(g)=\phi(cg)=\phi(cg_{1},...,cg_{|A|})=c^{|A|}\phi(g)$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: actually, never mind. Thanks. Indeed $\phi(\sum 1_{a_{i}})>0$ ,for $a_i\in A$ because otherwise we could scale it below $inf_{B}\phi(x)$.